# How to Show this thing up again? why it get easily diseapear? what keys i need to press

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

How To make this option appear as manually? What Button i need to press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show is the *Operator* box, it's used to set the parameters of your latest operation, if you do another action this panel will disappear and you won't have access to it anymore. But if you have just selected another object for example, the panel will disappear but you can simply press <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring it back.

So, for the *Sapling Tree Gen* addon, I guess you can only set the parameters once.